# MySQL - Multiple Selects in One Statement

Tags: mysql

I wanted to write a report to show the messages sent between users.

I'm only showing the last 200 users but I'm really struggling to find a way to do this without sending endless Selects to the Database.

Below is the basic select that I have. It shows a count of messages from one user to the other and then the reverse.

```
SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM msg WHERE sender_userid="3512" AND receiver_userid="3585";
SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM msg WHERE sender_userid="3585" AND receiver_userid="3512";
```

and here is another:

```
SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM msg WHERE sender_userid="3514" AND receiver_userid="3589";
SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM msg WHERE sender_userid="3589" AND receiver_userid="3514";
```

If I have around 200 users (and I can construct in MySQL Statements in PHP dynamically if needed) is there a way to do this kind of query in one query?

I then looked at a UNION ALL

```
SELECT COUNT(pid),sender_userid,receiver_userid FROM msg WHERE sender_userid="3512" AND receiver_userid="3585"
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(pid),sender_userid,receiver_userid FROM msg WHERE sender_userid="3585" AND receiver_userid="3512"
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(pid),sender_userid,receiver_userid FROM msg WHERE sender_userid="2953" AND receiver_userid="0473"
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(pid),sender_userid,receiver_userid FROM msg WHERE sender_userid="1235" AND receiver_userid="2953";
```

This could be constructed in PHP.

And it does give results that could be processed.

Is this the best approach? Is there a better way?

I can explain more/better if needed.

thx

Comment: I guess `sender_userid` is numeric data type. And with key on it. If so, then remove quotes - and pass your values as numeric literals. In some cases MySQL may not use index when string values (so, type-casing) are involved. As for the query - it's fine, `UNION ALL` is just a way to go here. Another option is to simulate via `GROUP BY` + `CASE`, but it won't use key (if any) - so I see `UNION` usage as a best approach here.

Comment: Is that not the same as `OR` and `GROUP BY`?